# add xml as a child node in exsiting xml using vb6

Tags: vb6

I have existing xml and trying to add an new xml as a child node.but it converting child xml in weird format.Child xml's all the tag < converted as &lt and all /> converted in &gt

I am using this vb code

```
objAdjoin.appendChild .createElement("DOCCHKLIST")
        objAdjoin.selectSingleNode("DOCCHKLIST").appendChild .createTextNode(DocCheckListXML)
```

Child XML :

```
   <DOCCHKLIST><DOCCHK><CDSEQGER>800</CDSEQGER><RLOSDOCSEQNO>MCV3453</RLOSDOCSEQNO><CLSEQNO>1</CLSEQNO></DOCCHK><DOCCHK><CDSEQGER>801</CDSEQGER><RLOSDOCSEQNO>MCV3453</RLOSDOCSEQNO><CLSEQNO>1</CLSEQNO></DOCCHK></DOCCHKLIST>
```

Output :

```
<Message><Output><AANO>MMG050069</AANO><LOADSCLSEQ>MMG050069</LOADSCLSEQ><RLOSCOLLSEQNO>SKE050003</RLOSCOLLSEQNO><CLCHKLSTTYPE>ASNB/UTRS</CLCHKLSTTYPE><DOCCHKLIST>&lt;DOCCHK&gt;&lt;CDSEQGER&gt;800&lt;/CDSEQGER&gt;&lt;RLOSDOCSEQNO&gt;MCV3453&lt;/RLOSDOCSEQNO&gt;&lt;CLSEQNO&gt;1&lt;/CLSEQNO&gt;&lt;/DOCCHK&gt;&lt;DOCCHK&gt;&lt;CDSEQGER&gt;801&lt;/CDSEQGER&gt;&lt;RLOSDOCSEQNO&gt;MCV3453&lt;/RLOSDOCSEQNO&gt;&lt;CLSEQNO&gt;1&lt;/CLSEQNO&gt;&lt;/DOCCHK&gt;</DOCCHKLIST><Status>00</Status><ErrorMessage>Processing Complete</ErrorMessage></Output></Message>
```

Comment: I think it is is because you are adding it as text node.  This will take it as text and convert all of the reserved characters.  You could use the LoadXml method from the DOMDocument6 (if you are using that one), you can then append the node from there into the DOCChkList.

Comment: @lardymonkey i am using DOMDocument60 but while using LoadXml , it gives "Type Mismatch , compiler error"

Comment: Hi @vim, just to confirm the text you have in the child node xml above is what you are loading? Just wondered because you are closing it all with ]]></docchklist> but I couldn't see where that was opened.  Try removing the ]]> if the last closing tag is valid.

Comment: @lardymonkey hi just updated the child xml

Comment: Hi, Do you get the type mismatch when you load the child xml?  I will post the code in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without adding the child nodes individually I have managed to get it to work as follows:

```
Private Sub Command_Click()
Dim objDomDoc   As DOMDocument60
Dim objDom1     As DOMDocument60
Dim strParent   As String
Dim strChild    As String
Dim objAdJoin   As IXMLDOMElement

strParent = "<Message><Output><AANO>MMG050069</AANO><LOADSCLSEQ>MMG050069</LOADSCLSEQ><RLOSCOLLSEQNO>SKE050003</RLOSCOLLSEQNO><CLCHKLSTTYPE>ASNB/UTRS</CLCHKLSTTYPE></Output></Message>"
strChild = "<DOCCHKLIST><DOCCHK><CDSEQGER>800</CDSEQGER><RLOSDOCSEQNO>MCV3453</RLOSDOCSEQNO><CLSEQNO>1</CLSEQNO></DOCCHK><DOCCHK><CDSEQGER>801</CDSEQGER><RLOSDOCSEQNO>MCV3453</RLOSDOCSEQNO><CLSEQNO>1</CLSEQNO></DOCCHK></DOCCHKLIST>"

Set objDomDoc = New DOMDocument60
Set objDom1 = New DOMDocument60

objDomDoc.loadXML (strParent)
objDom1.loadXML strChild

Set objAdJoin = objDomDoc.firstChild

objAdJoin.appendChild objDomDoc.createElement("DOCCHKLIST")
objAdJoin.selectSingleNode("DOCCHKLIST").appendChild objDom1.firstChild

Debug.Print objAdJoin.xml

End Sub
```

You will need to check the parseError property to see if there have been any issues with the load.  You will also end up with two nodes called DOCCHKLIST.